# Debugger shows not existing properties of an object

Tags: visual-studio

I am using [Svg .Net lib](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG). Here is my method code

```
public void X()
    {
        Svg.SvgDocument svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(Path);
        foreach (var child in svgDocument.Children)
        {
            foreach (var step in child.Children)
            {
                if (step.ID.StartsWith("node"))
                {
                    var el = step.Children[2];
                    var id = el.Content;
                }
            }

        }
        
    }
```

And here is what I can see  in a debugger:
[image]
My question is how I can see Bounds property if object does not have it?
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The _object_ has that property but the type you're referring to it by may not. Eg `Cat` may inherit from `Animal` and both could store a cat object, but the `Animal` type may not have cat-specific properties in its interface. Try casting your element to be a `SvgText` rather than an `SvgElement` (I'm not familiar with the types personally but that's what the watch window is  treating the object as)... `if (el is SvgText) {var textElement = (SvgText) el; ... }`

Comment: Yea, it is an inheritance problem. Thanks for clearing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger always shows the properties of the *actual* (dynamic) instance of the object, not the static type of the variable you're referring to. It tries to give you as much information about the object as possible. If you check the third column in the watch window, it tells you the static type of the variable (`SvgElement`) and its dynamic type (`SvgText`) in braces. Expanding a variable shows the properties and fields of the dynamic type.